# selenium get content of custom html tag

Tags: selenium, selenium-chromedriver

This is my code:

```
private void TEST()
{
    if (driver == null)
    {
        driver = new ChromeDriver();
        driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("https://address/login-page");
    }
    var usernameTextbox = driver.FindElements(By.XPath("//input[@placeholder='Username']"));
    if (usernameTextbox != null && usernameTextbox.Any())
        usernameTextbox[0].SendKeys("0966875066");
    var passTextbox = driver.FindElements(By.XPath("//input[@placeholder='Pass word']"));
    if (passTextbox != null && usernameTextbox.Any())
        passTextbox[0].SendKeys("123456");
    var btn = driver.FindElements(By.LinkText(("Login")));
    if (btn != null && btn.Any())
        btn[0].Click();

    driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("https://www.address/profile-page");


    var html = driver.PageSource;
     //can not find <top-up tag 

}
```

I cannot find all the elements in the page (As the picture I send below). Although when I ctrl + 12. I see them.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nRY0A.png)

Comment: Provide some waits before get the `driver.PageSource` and see any difference?

Comment: @KunduK. I tried, but the result is still the same: driver.Manage().Timeouts().ImplicitWait = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10);
            Thread.Sleep(7000);